# How to store the ID of selected dropdown value in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two class models, which translate to two MySQL database tables. One is `employees` and the other is `projects`. They have a one-to-many relationship, i.e one project can have several employees. In my web form when registering an employee, I have a dropdown containing the projects.  Table `employees`, has a foreign key referencing `projects` table and thus the `employees` table has an `Integer` column (`emp_project_id`) as the foreign key from the `projects` table. How do I save the ID when a project is selected from the dropdown?

```
class Employee(UserMixin, db.Model):
    """
    Create Employee table
    """

   # Ensures table will be named in plural and not in singular 
   # as in the name of the model
   __tablename__ = 'employees'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   emp_number = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
   username = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
   email = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
   emp_name = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True)
   password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
   emp_project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), nullable=False)
```

And here is the `projects` table

```
class Project(db.Model):
    """
    Create a Project table
    """

    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

    pro_subprojects = db.relationship('Subproject', backref='sp_project', 
                                lazy='dynamic')
    pro_employees = db.relationship('Employee', backref='emp_project', 
                                lazy='dynamic')
```

Kindly refer me to a resource I can go through too if possible, since I have not found the solution in their documentation.

Here is the class from `forms.py` that creates the form

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for users to create new account
    """
    project = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Project.query.all(), 
                                                    get_label="name")
    subproject = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Subproject.query.all(), 
                                                    get_label="name")
    emp_number = StringField('Employee Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    emp_name = StringField('Full Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[
                                            DataRequired(), 
                                            EqualTo('confirm_password')
                                        ])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

Here is what I have added on my `views.py`:

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """
    Handle requests to the /register route
    Add an employee to the database through the registration form
    """
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        employee = Employee(project=form.project.data,
                            subproject=form.subproject.data,
                            emp_number=form.emp_number.data,
                            email=form.email.data,
                            username=form.username.data,
                            emp_name=form.emp_name.data,
                            password=form.password.data)

        # add employee to the database
        db.session.add(employee)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have registered successfully. You can now log in.')
```

When I try to register an employee however, I get an error like `TypeError: 'project' is an invalid keyword argument for Employee`. Kindly help

Comment: are you following this tutorial? : https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-one

Comment: Sure. I am following that one, though developing something a little different

Comment: you should have all elements from html form in dictionary [flask.request.form](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object)

Comment: @furas kindly elaborate more, especially with some few lines of code. I am still a beginner in Flask

Comment: please add your html code where you get your select box

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi I just added the `forms.py` class that generates the form

Comment: @DaktariDindi I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what is said in [the documentation  for QuerySelectedField](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.2/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.django.fields) :

> The data property actually will store/keep an ORM model instance, not
>   the ID.

Now I understand your problem change your view like this :

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """
    Handle requests to the /register route
    Add an employee to the database through the registration form
    """
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        employee = Employee(
                            emp_number=form.emp_number.data,
                            email=form.email.data,
                            username=form.username.data,
                            emp_name=form.emp_name.data,
                            password=form.password.data)
        project=form.project.data  #an instance of Project Class
        subproject=form.subproject.data #an instance of SubProject Class
        project.pro_subproject.append(subproject) 
        project.pro_employee.append(employee)
        # add employee to the database
        db.session.add(employee)
        db.session.add(subproject)
        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have registered successfully. You can now log in.')
```

[Here is an explanation of that :](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html)

> A one to many relationships places a foreign key on the child table
>   referencing the parent. **relationship() is then specified on the
>   parent, as referencing a collection of items represented by the
>   child:**

This means in your project table the field pro_employees and pro_subproject are lists of employee (n) and sub_project(n).

Comment: I think we are almost there, @EspoirMurhabazi. I'm now getting an error that `emp_project_id` cannot be `null`. When the data is being sent to the database, the `emp_project_id` field is left empty, yet it is a foreign key, thus `not null`

Comment: Try to print project to check if it s not null , and by saving the project first  so put db.session.add (project) before employees